# How to Intercept and Alter Insert Statement in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Recently i had to add a new Datasource to an existing Datawarehouse. This Datasource had some Tablefields which exceeds my current Fieldsize in the Datawarehouse. I should not alter the Fieldsize of the Datawarehouse due to non-technical Reasons.

What i want to do is use the Interception-System of Entity Framework to check the Insert and trim Fields to the defined length (Available in Attributes, Code First Approach)

What i got so far:

```
public class StringTrimmerInterceptor : IDbCommandTreeInterceptor
{
    void IDbCommandTreeInterceptor.TreeCreated(DbCommandTreeInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
    {
        if (interceptionContext.OriginalResult.DataSpace != DataSpace.SSpace)
            return;

        var insertCommand = interceptionContext.Result as DbInsertCommandTree;
        if (insertCommand != null)
        {
            //Check and Trim oversized Fields

        }

    }
}
```

Above Code works as far as finding the Correct Insert-Statements i want to alter. What i want to know is How to actually alter and execute them.

I did find some examples of how to alter Query but nothing realy to altering Inserts/Updates.

The result should be something like this:
If i try to save a customer with the Name :"MyCustomerWithanUnreasonableLongName" i want to save only the number of charaters specified in the Model like "MyCustomerWitha"